# Cannot represent Double 'Infinity' as a Decimal, salesforce

Tags: apex

I am having issues with an apex code we are trying to get working. I keep getting the error;

"System.MathException: Cannot represent Double 'Infinity' as a Decimal: (System Code)"

```
decimal rho = 1000;
decimal mu = 0.0019;
beta = 0.0757;
decimal r_b_eq8 =   (0.33 * math.exp(0.76 * math.log(9.81) * math.exp(0.52 * math.log(rho / mu)) * math.exp(1.28 * math.log((math.exp((1/3)*math.log(beta)))))));
```

The issue occurs when we try to compute the math.log(rho / mu) portion of the code. I have tried rounding the result of rho / mu, defining it as a double, many other things. I have tried setting the division portion of the problem equal to another variable and substituted,

```
alpha = rho / mu;
... * math.log(alpha) ...
```

with little succes. Is this an issue with the way we have defined our variables as decimals? The math.log works just fine with the 9.81 and also with "beta" as the end.

We do the calculations with excel and many other programs and never have an issue like this. We are running our code this way due to the inability to compute (rho / mu) ^ 0.52 in salesforce without the math.log/exp trick. Is there a way around this or another way to computer the raising of (rho / mu) ^ 0.52 which wouldn't give us this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a different problem. Using Eclipse's Execute Anonymous, I entered:

```
decimal rho = 1000;
decimal mu = 0.0019;
System.debug(math.log(rho/mu));
```

And in the log was:

> USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|13.173656671791878

**Update**

I broke your equation down into intermediate results to find the problem. It breaks on the `math.exp(0.76*...)` segment.

```
decimal rho = 1000;
decimal mu = 0.0019;
decimal beta = 0.0757;
decimal result1 = math.log((math.exp((1/3)*math.log(beta))));
decimal result2 = math.exp(1.28 * result1);
decimal result3 = math.exp(0.52 * math.log(rho / mu));
double result4 = math.log(9.81) * result3 * result2; // = 2155.909650963165

// Trying to calculate result5 results in the error.
double result5 = (double)math.exp(0.76 * result4);
```

Trying to calculate e^(2155*0.76) is approximately equal to 3.87x 10^711, a very large number. This calculation seems to be overflowing what Apex can handle.

Comment: I am running this in Salesforce Apex... Why would I run it in Eclipse? Second, it has to be with the log because I get the same issue when I remove all other code.

Comment: @Mike Chale using the Force Plugin for Eclipse, so he is also running in Salesforce Apex.

Comment: @ Mike. Makes sense. Is there another way to compute the (rho/mhu ^ 0.52)? This is our ultimate goal. The exp/log has been our work around.

Comment: That part works fine (it's result3 in my testing, above.) It's when you do that part with e^(0.76*...) that it fails.

Comment: Your right Mike. I looked back over our equations and the ultimate issue is that there should have been () around 0.76 * math.log(9.81)

(0.33 * (math.exp(0.76 * math.log(9.81)) * math.exp(0.52 * math.log(rho / mu)) *

It represents 9.81^0.76. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is exactly  datatype overflow please find the analysis breakdown below

```
decimal rho = 1000;
decimal mu = 0.0019;
decimal beta = 0.0757;
decimal t =0.76 * math.log(9.81) * math.exp(0.52 * math.log(rho / mu)) * math.exp(1.28 * math.log((math.exp((1/3)*math.log(beta)))));
System.debug(t);
decimal r_b_eq8 =   (0.33 * math.exp(705)); // works fine 
  r_b_eq8 =   (0.33 * math.exp(710)); // breaks here  so the problem is data type overflow.
```

r_b_eq8 =   (0.33 * math.exp(t)); // t is too large to 710